# Выбор комнат в чате

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток. Возник вопрос, который так и не могу реализовать. В чате, допустим, "ПРИХОЖАЯ" по адресу `chat/index.php`, в которой есть названия комнат, например, "ЗНАКОМИМСЯ", у которой адрес `chat/index.php?room=1`, комната "ИНТИМ" по адресу `chat/index.php?room=2` и так далее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать так, чтобы проходя по ссылке в комнату, все данные с основной страницы `chat/index.php` убирались и выдавалась чистая страница, на которой я бы мог в дальнейшем реализовывать мною задуманное

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rooms");
if($query){
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<p><a href='rooms.php?room=".$row['id']."'>".$row['name_room']."</a></p>\n";
     }
}elseif(!$query){
  echo 'Ошибка при подключении, пожалуйста, зайдите позднее.';
}
?>
```

Это код на выборку с базы названия комнат.

Comment: Что - то код не форматируется о_О

Comment: @NoProblems, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: спасибо, запомнил )

Answer (score 1):

Собственно вот так и реализовал... кидаю код на всякий случай, вдруг кому то понадобится из начинающих, как я.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET" && isset($_GET['room']) && !empty($_GET['room'])) {
    $room = $_GET['room'];
    if ($room <= isset($room)) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT name_room FROM rooms WHERE id='$room'");
        if ($query) {
            $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
        }
    }
}
echo "<center><h3>" . $res['name_room'] . "</h3></center>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty ($_POST['room'])) {
    ///индексная страница со списком комнат
} else {
    // SELECT * FROM room WHERE id=$_POST['room'] и так далее 
}
```

Это в общих чертах. Ну естественно в начале проверить не пустой ли пришел POST и вообще что в нем пришло.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: так и не смог сделать то, о чем Вы говорили... пришлось комнаты делать в отдельном файле php)с помощью GET)

Comment: И вправду не получилось бы. Что это мне в головe пришло писать POST вместо GET.

Comment: да нет, я сообразил, что в место POSTa надо было делать GET, но все ровно не получилось сделать все на одной странице)